# Program not working on another computer, Unhandled exception. Parameter is not valid

Tags: vb.net, exe, unhandled

Been trying to fix this program for 5 hours now by searching forums, very tired by now. Nothing has been helpful, and I think my patience may have ran out.

Here's an list of what i am doing.

1st- I "publish" the program which compiles everything into a .exe and a resource folder
2nd- works flawlessly on my computer
3rd- copy it to my other computer(eventually renaming folders and everything to be exactly the same)
4th- open the .exe, this ridiculously unhelpful error pops up saying there was an unhandled exception in my application
5th- continue any way, my form is missing the background, 3 more images, 2 labels and a couple of drawings. but it has 6 labels and 2 picture boxes, I am not understanding why the labels, the background and this other picture box is not loading... this is very very frustrating and any small logical suggestions would be helpful.

Note: the program is 1378 lines long

Comment: Is your app save images (programatically)?

Comment: It is calling them, not saving them.

Comment: I would suggest to add some kind of logging to find out what exactly is happening.

Comment: Could you post the exception with the stack trace?

Comment: I think I may have found the problem; I was calling my images from a path that didn't exist on the other computers. I am changing the paths of my files to see if this improves my situation. I will give my answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Are the images compiled as resources? If not, they may need to explicitly be copied during the deployment.

Comment: I just installed a newer VB.Net onto the one that's not working, I am also rebuilding the exe file with update resources. However I am not sure if the resources will affect it much as it worked on the other computer that it was created on.

Comment: Wasn't sure what the dev environment was. For VS, in the properties explorer for each image, you can choose whether to compile as resource (or not).  You can also choose there whether to copy it with the build output.  Neither of these are on by default IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. My images were called from C:/... they needed so be called from My.Resources.